# Create & animate two sine wave path with svg and link them to different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am not very familiar with javascript and jQuery coding thats why I tried to find similar projects, which can help to solve my problem.
I am trying to create and animate two sine waves. My idea can be based on the following codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPjwGw.

The basic idea what I have is, to have one original sine wave and one that displays the changes in the frequency, amplitude etc. Quite similar to the shadow button. But I could not create a standard sine wave. In the example the value of the wave is rising (the sine wave is getting bigger and longer), but it actually should stay constant.

Also the colors of the wave should be able to change by the user, for example if i want to hide both of the sine waves and show instead two balls which look like "bouncing". So they are linked to the path of the sine waves. To have a better visibility, one of the balls should be also moveable with a slider(range) controller. This should actually be the frequency range slider.

So i have a full sine wave of 2pi or 360°, my range slider is able to move one ball along the sine wave path and continue the animation from there. So it should look like they bounce asynchronous.

Because of my present problem, one of the balls(which is being modified) shell bounce "backwards" at a frequency of 180°, so somehow an "if condition" needs to be implemented. I hope i could describe my problem to you

I tried out some things, but could not achieve a simple sine wave. As i looked through the code, many stuff appeared quite unknown to me, so i very appreciate some coding help. Underneath i cut down the code to the basic, just to show you the two round objects and the achieved sine wave https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyaMYm.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://jaromvogel.com/js/lib/path-data-polyfill.js"></script>
<style>
.graph-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: ;
  right: 0;
}

.svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app-container" ng-app="waveApp" ng-controller="waveCtrl">
    <div class="graph-container">
        <svg class="svg" width="300" height="100" ng-style="{'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'}">
            <path class="sine-wave-reference" ng-show="shadow" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"/>
            <path class="sine-wave" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg" width="300" height="100"">
        <circle cx="5" cy="50" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red"/>
        <circle cx="20" cy="50" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('waveApp', []);

app.controller('waveCtrl', function($scope) {

    var path = $('.sine-wave');
    var reference = $('.sine-wave-reference');

    $scope.x = 0;
    $scope.offset = 0;

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.frequency = 3;
        $scope.amplitude = 50;
        $scope.shadow = false;
        $scope.framerate = 60;
        $scope.increment = 5;
        $scope.rotation = 0;
    };

    $scope.reset();

    $scope.pathFunction = function (x) {
        var result =
            // Function to determine curve
            // f(x)= a * math.sin(b*(x+c))+d
            // a=amplitude , b=frequency, c=move x-direction, d=move y-direction
            (Math.sin(Math.sqrt(x*$scope.frequency)-$scope.offset))*(0.8 * $scope.amplitude);
        return result;
    };

    $scope.createGraph = function (wave) {
        $scope.x = 2;
        var origin = [
            {
                'type': 'M',
                'values': [0,150]
            }
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
            var point = {
                x: $scope.x,
                y: 150 - $scope.pathFunction($scope.x) 
            };
            origin.push({
                'type': 'L',
                'values': [
                    point.x ,
                    point.y
                ]
            });
            $scope.x = $scope.x + 1;
        }
        wave[0].setPathData(origin);
    };

    $scope.createGraph(reference);

    $scope.play = true;

    $scope.animate = function () {
        if ($scope.play === true) {
            $scope.offset += ($scope.increment / $scope.framerate);
            $scope.createGraph(path);
            setTimeout(function () {
                requestAnimationFrame($scope.animate);  
            },(1000 / $scope.framerate));
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame($scope.animate);
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As an observation: for a  "bouncing" effect I would animate the object along the path. I wouldn't animate the path. Also a  "bouncing" ball is not moving on a sine wave, [it's moving on a series of parabolas](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1428&bih=844&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=qrE0XMiuHMGFjLsP_6mfyAw&q=bouncing+ball+curve&oq=bouncing+ball+curve&gs_l=img.3..0.15209.17022..17391...0.0..0.122.714.0j6......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24.uXq4I9AFoHc)

Comment: Well, i try to explain my problem as good as possible once more. What i would like to have is a sine wave which seems to move periodic (animation), like in the first codepen. If now an object is included, for example a ball, it should have the same periodic move (path?) as the sine wave. And if you turn the color of the sine wave the same as the background, it should look like the ball is moving periodic up and down, because the sine wave is not visible anymore.
And also the sine wave should be standard and not getting bigger, as i explained above.